# Cant run a DropWizard server side properly

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, jersey, jetty, dropwizard

I am developing a android and iOS app that needs to have a RESTful server side.
Until today i used Jersey with RunJettyRun on eclipse but i decided to start using something new and better! and i moved to DropWizard and IntelliJ IDEA

These are the softwares i got installed and things i took care of already :
- Java 8
- Maven 3.1.1
- Environment variables for Maven and for Java.

Well for now what i did is following the tutorial of Getting Started of DropWizard on their website.
I did exactly as they said and at the end i tried to run the jar i got from the mvn package command in the IntelliJ Terminal. The result was in the output:

```
usage: java -jar dropwizard-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
       [-h] [-v] {server,check} ...

positional arguments:
  {server,check}         available commands

optional arguments:
  -h, --help             show this help message and exit
  -v, --version          show the application version and exit

Process finished with exit code 0
```

The code :

Resource Class:

```
@Path("/hello-world")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class HelloResource {
    private final String template;
    private final String defaultName;
    private final AtomicLong counter;

    public HelloResource(String template, String defaultName) {
        this.template = template;
        this.defaultName = defaultName;
        this.counter = new AtomicLong();
    }

    @GET
    @Timed
    public Saying sayHello(@QueryParam("name") Optional<String> name) {
        final String value = String.format(template, name.or(defaultName));
        return new Saying(counter.incrementAndGet(), value);
    }
}
```

Configuration Class:
    import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
    import io.dropwizard.Configuration;
    import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotEmpty;

```
import javax.validation.Valid;

/**
 * Created by Ido on 2/25/2015.
 */
public class Conf extends Configuration {
    @NotEmpty
    private String template;

    @NotEmpty
    private String defaultName = "Stranger";

    @JsonProperty
    public String getTemplate() {
        return template;
    }

    @JsonProperty
    public void setTemplate(String template) {
        this.template = template;
    }

    @JsonProperty
    public String getDefaultName() {
        return defaultName;
    }

    @JsonProperty
    public void setDefaultName(String name) {
        this.defaultName = name;
    }
}
```

Representation Class:
    public class Saying {
        private long id;

```
    @Length(max = 3)
    private String content;

    public Saying() {
        // Jackson deserialization
    }

    public Saying(long id, String content) {
        this.id = id;
        this.content = content;
    }

    @JsonProperty
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @JsonProperty
    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }
}
```

Service Class:

```
import io.dropwizard.Application;
import io.dropwizard.java8.Java8Bundle;
import io.dropwizard.setup.Bootstrap;
import io.dropwizard.setup.Environment;

/**
 * Created by Ido on 2/25/2015.
 */
public class ExampleService extends Application<Conf> {

    public static void main(String [] args) throws Exception {
        new ExampleService().run(args);
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "Hello World";
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(Bootstrap<Conf> bootstrap) {
        bootstrap.addBundle(new Java8Bundle());
    }

    @Override
    public void run(Conf conf, Environment environment) throws Exception {
        final HelloResource resource = new HelloResource(
                conf.getTemplate(),
                conf.getDefaultName()
        );

        final TemplateHealthCheck healthCheck =
                new TemplateHealthCheck(conf.getTemplate());
        environment.healthChecks().register("template", healthCheck);
        environment.
                jersey().register(resource);
    }
}
```

POM File

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>ido.dropwizard.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>dropwizard</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>


    <properties>
        <dropwizard.version>0.7.1</dropwizard.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.dropwizard</groupId>
            <artifactId>dropwizard-core</artifactId>
            <version>${dropwizard.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.dropwizard.modules</groupId>
            <artifactId>dropwizard-java8</artifactId>
            <version>0.7.0-1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.dropwizard.modules</groupId>
            <artifactId>dropwizard-java8-auth</artifactId>
            <version>0.7.0-1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.dropwizard.modules</groupId>
            <artifactId>dropwizard-java8-jdbi</artifactId>
            <version>0.7.0-1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <createDependencyReducedPom>true</createDependencyReducedPom>
                    <filters>
                        <filter>
                            <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                            <excludes>
                                <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                            </excludes>
                        </filter>
                    </filters>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer"/>
                                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                    <mainClass>ido.dropwizard.example.ExampleService</mainClass>
                                </transformer>
                            </transformers>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>


            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>
```

I added the entire code because i really needs an answer because i gone through this problem on some other tutorials on youtube and google and couldn't get it to work...
BTW when i tried to test this i typed on a browser - http://localhost:8080/hello-world/something and also http://localhost:8080/hello-world  => Didn't worked :)

Well i will be very grateful for any help , Thanks :)

Comment: What command did you run? It shows the app isn't running from what you are showing. When ever you see a help menu from the command line, it means your command is incorrect

Comment: Do this, put the yaml config file in the same directory as the jar, then `cd` to the directory (I don't use Itellij so I have no idea how to do that from their console). If you have maven installed locally in your system, I'd just go from the command line, and use `java -jar dropwizard-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar server config.yml`. If you followed the instructions to the t from the getting started, that should work.

Comment: Better yet, don't put the config in the location of the jar. It will get deleted on a `clean`. Instead put it in the project root. Then `cd` to the project root (if you haven't built yet, then `mvn clean package`), then `java -jar target/dropwizard-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar server config.yml`

Comment: If you don't have a config file (which you haven't shown), then you should go over the guide again, where they show what it should look like, and will have examples. This config file is needed. That's how your `Conf` class gets it values

Comment: peeskillet first of thank you very much because when i tried to execute the jar by simply click on it and run i didnt worked because i needed to give the {server} {config.yml} values... In short IT WORKED! :)

Comment: But can u give a big answer to this question for item on the dropwizard why it is needed ?
I understood the Classes : Resource , Config and Application but i couldn't understand the maven POM file , each command why it is needed

Comment: Also what the mvn package command does ? and how it does it with the pom file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71890/discussion-between-ido-magor-and-peeskillet).

Comment: `mvn package` just builds your jar. It has nothing to do with the dropwizard/java/jar command. First you build the jar, then you run it with the java jar command. As far as the pom, you probably need to do some studying on Maven. In short, pom stands for Project Object Model, so it's a model of your project. You have dependencies and plugins. Plugins assist in the build. When you run the `mvn package` it builds and by using the `shade `plugin` it builds everything (all dependies and your project) into one jar

Comment: Well thanks alot.
Discussion cant be closed

Answer (score 0):

Dropwizard takes the first command line argument and dispatches it to a matching command. In this case, the commands available is server and check, which runs your application as an HTTP server. The server command requires a configuration file, you can do it like this :

```
java -jar target/dropwizard-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar server config.yml
```

if it is in a subfolder

```
java -jar target/dropwizard-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar server conf/config.yml
```

if you do not have config.yml, create one like this template:

[config.yml](https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/blob/master/dropwizard-example/example.yml)

Answer (score 0):

Try to edit the run configuration by adding the arguments

[image]